# Create QuickBook purchase Order in java

Tags: java, quickbooks

Is it possible to create a Quick Books purchase order using java?
I am planning to use QB web connector. Does it support?

Comment: I asked a question. No one reply  here.https://intuitpartnerplatform.lc.intuit.com/questions/794240-is-it-possible-to-create-a-quick-books-purchase-order-using-java-i-am-planning-to-use-qb-web-connector-does-it-support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is certainly possible to do.

Here's a good [overview of the QuickBooks Web Connector protocol](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QuickBooks_Web_Connector_Overview). It's a pretty simple set of SOAP web service methods you can implement in order for the Web Connector to relay data to QuickBooks.

Once you have that implemented, you can send a qbXML request to QuickBooks to add a Purchase Order.

Here's an [example qbXML request for creating a Purchase Order](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QbXML_for_Adding_a_Purchase_Order).

You can use the [QuickBooks OSR](https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html) for further qbXML reference.

If you look in the [QuickBooks SDK](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb) it includes sample code for implementing a Java web service for the Web Connector.